# arcanist error with RocksDB on fresh install (Mac OS X)

Tags: phabricator, arcanist, rocksdb

I have installed a fresh copy of arcanist on to Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11.4) into `/usr/local/phabricator/arcanist`.

If I first `cd` into `/usr/local/phabricator/arcanist` and run either `bin/arc` or just `arc` (as I added `/usr/local/phabricator/arcanist/bin` to my `PATH`) then all is fine. However if I try and run `arc lint` from my rocksdb directory on my system then I always get a fatal error, the output looks like this:

```
$ arc lint --trace
 ARGV  '/usr/local/phabricator/arcanist/bin/../scripts/arcanist.php' 'lint' '--trace'
 LOAD  Loaded "phutil" from "/usr/local/phabricator/libphutil/src".
 LOAD  Loaded "arcanist" from "/usr/local/phabricator/arcanist/src".
Config: Did not find user configuration at "/Users/aretter/.arcrc".
Config: Did not find system configuration at "/etc/arcconfig".
Working Copy: Reading .arcconfig from "/Users/aretter/code/rocksdb/.arcconfig".
Working Copy: Path "/Users/aretter/code/rocksdb" is part of `git` working copy "/Users/aretter/code/rocksdb".
Working Copy: Project root is at "/Users/aretter/code/rocksdb".
Config: Did not find local configuration at "/Users/aretter/code/rocksdb/.git/arc/config".
Loading phutil library from '/Users/aretter/code/rocksdb/arcanist_util'...

[2016-06-14 09:31:17] EXCEPTION: (PhutilMissingSymbolException) Failed to load class or interface 'ArcanistBaseWorkflow': the class or interface 'ArcanistBaseWorkflow' is not defined in the library map for any loaded phutil library.

If you are not a developer, this almost always means that a library is out of date. For example, you may have upgraded `phabricator` without upgrading `libphutil`, or vice versa. It might also mean that you need to restart Apache or PHP-FPM. Make sure all libraries are up to date and all services have been restarted.

If you are a developer and this symbol was recently added or moved, your library map may need to be rebuilt. You can rebuild the map by running 'arc liberate'. For more information, see:

https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/adding_new_classes/ at [<phutil>/src/__phutil_library_init__.php:25]
arcanist(head=master, ref.master=c13e5a629535), arcanist_util(head=java-wb-save-restore-points, ref.master=fda098461b3f, ref.java-wb-save-restore-points=dd6d2e75d836), phutil(head=master, ref.master=fb1e159d3640)
  #0 __phutil_autoload(string)
  #1 spl_autoload_call(string) called at [<arcanist_util>/config/FacebookArcanistConfiguration.php:7]
  #2 include_once(string) called at [<phutil>/src/moduleutils/PhutilBootloader.php:226]
  #3 PhutilBootloader::executeInclude(string) called at [<phutil>/src/moduleutils/PhutilBootloader.php:216]
  #4 PhutilBootloader::loadLibrarySource(string, string) called at [<phutil>/src/symbols/PhutilSymbolLoader.php:381]
  #5 PhutilSymbolLoader::loadSymbol(array) called at [<phutil>/src/symbols/PhutilSymbolLoader.php:256]
  #6 PhutilSymbolLoader::selectAndLoadSymbols() called at [<phutil>/src/__phutil_library_init__.php:22]
  #7 __phutil_autoload(string)
  #8 spl_autoload_call(string) called at [<arcanist>/scripts/arcanist.php:186]
```

Please note that I have tried reinstalling it and also running `arc liberate`, but neither has fixed the issue.

Can someone tell me what is wrong on my system?

I have also checked with Git that my arcanist is indeed correct and up-to-date:

```
$ cd /usr/local/phabricator/arcanist
$ git remote -v
origin  github.com/phacility/arcanist.git (fetch)
origin github.com/phacility/arcanist.git (push)

$ git status
On branch master Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'. nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

I also tried reinstalling via this mechanism:

```
$ cd /usr/local/phabricator
$ rm -rf arcanist libphutil
$ git clone https://github.com/phacility/libphutil.git
$ git clone https://github.com/phacility/arcanist.git
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> arcanist_util(head=java-wb-save-restore-points, ref.master=fda098461b3f, ref.java-wb-save-restore-points=dd6d2e75d836)

This doesn't look like a fresh copy of arcanist to me from source, at least the upstream isn't responsible for "arcanist_util". Where did you get it from? I would delete it, and pull directly from GitHub. http://github.com/phacility/arcanist

Comment: Okay some progress, it seems that the error only occurs in actual fact if I run `arc lint` inside my rocksdb directory. From the trace logging above it says: `Loading phutil library from '/Users/aretter/code/rocksdb/arcanist_util'` so I think the issue is something wrong in RocksDB arcanist config - https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/tree/master/arcanist_util.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you put me onto the correct path. I have now sent a PR to RocksDB to fix their `arcanist_util` module for the latest version of Arcanist - https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/pull/1168